# Get json value with hyphen from response

Tags: karate

I have seen the [note about quoting json fields with hyphens](https://github.com/intuit/karate#header) but how do we access json from the response if it has hyphens?

Response is along the lines of

```
{ cancel-account: "Please don't do it!" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work,

```
* def response = { cancel-account: "Please don't do it!" }
* def cancelAccount = response['cancel-account']
* print cancelAccount
```